# Async multiple requests with async tasks?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, web-scraping, async-await

I have quite simple Python scraper:

```
async def process_shoes_by_keyword():
    print('START PROCESS NEW SHOES ' + str(datetime.now()))
    session = requests.Session()
    global old_shoes_db
    shoes_to_save_tmp = list()
    keywords = read_keywords()
    responses = await fetch_multiple_main_sites()
    try:
        for response in responses:
            if keywords and response is not None and response.startswith('{"success":true'):
                shoes, category = filter_shoes_json(response)
                shoes_lite = filter_shoes(shoes)
                if shoes_lite and category != '':
                    shoes_to_save = list()
                    for shoe, action in shoe_producer(shoes_lite, old_shoes_db, keywords, category):
                        # sending messages
                        if action == 'new':
                            send_message(session, shoe, category, 'NEW SHOES')
                        # update db
                        if action == 'sold':
                            shoes_to_save.append(cut_to_save_new_shoes(shoe, False, category))
                        else:
                            shoes_to_save.append(cut_to_save_new_shoes(shoe, True, category))
                    shoes_to_save_tmp.append(shoes_to_save)
            else:
                print(
                    str(datetime.now()) + ' [ERROR] Something went wrong when retrieving page. Skipping...')
        shoes_to_save_merged = shoes_to_save_tmp[0] + shoes_to_save_tmp[1] + shoes_to_save_tmp[2] + shoes_to_save_tmp[3]
        save_shoes(shoes_to_save_merged)
        old_shoes_db = shoes_to_save_merged
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(datetime.now()) + ' [ERROR] Something went wrong when retrieving page. Skipping... Exception: ' + str(
            e))
    print('END PROCESS NEW SHOES ' + str(datetime.now()))


async def process_sizes():
    print('START PROCESS SIZES ' + str(datetime.now()))
    session = requests.Session()
    links = read_links()
    global old_sizes
    sizes_to_save = []
    responses = await fetch_multiple(links)
    old_sizes_dict = {size['id']: size for size in old_sizes}
    for response in responses:
        if response is not None and response.startswith('<!DOCTYPE html>\n'):
            sizes = filter_sizes_json(response)
            category = get_category(response)
            filtered_sizes = filter_sizes(sizes)
            if filtered_sizes and category != '':
                sizes_to_save.append(cut_to_save_sizes(filtered_sizes))
                new_sizes = compare_sizes(filtered_sizes, old_sizes_dict)
                if new_sizes:
                    send_message(session, new_sizes, category, 'SIZES UPDATE')
        else:
            print(str(datetime.now()) + ' [ERROR] Something went wrong when retrieving page. Skipping...')
    save_external_sizes(sizes_to_save)
    old_sizes = sizes_to_save
    print('END PROCESS SIZES ' + str(datetime.now()))


async def main():
    print('START ' + str(datetime.now()))
    shoes_task = process_shoes_by_keyword()
    sizes_task = process_sizes()
    await asyncio.gather(shoes_task, sizes_task)
    print('END ' + str(datetime.now()))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
        time.sleep(1)
```

One of functions for fetching urls:

```
async def fetch_multiple(urls):
    async with CloudflareScraper() as session:
        tasks = [fetch(session, url) for url in urls]
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return responses


async def fetch(session, url):
    proxy = get_random_proxy()
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 '
    }
    async with session.get(url, proxy=proxy, timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(sock_connect=15, sock_read=15),
                           headers=headers) as response:
        print(str(datetime.now()) + ' [' + str(response.status) + '] ' + url)
        return await response.text()
```

The problem is I want

```
process_shoes_by_keyword() and process_sizes()
```

To run independently of each other without waiting for each other to end while maintaining asynchronous requests (I need to fetch responses from URLs as fast as possible).

I tried using Threads, but with no effect.

Is there any way to achieve this?